# "Guess the number" JS game function problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

Although not a single error was shown in DevKit in Chrome, my program seems to not recognize the conditionals right... The problem stands somewhere along the lines of the "game()" function. It doesn't recognize if a number is higher or lower than it. It either is an attention mistake, or I just missed something important regarding programming. I have to say that I started learning JS a couple of days ago, so I just want to improve my skills and do some practice.

```js
var difBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName('difficulty');
var easy = document.getElementById('easy');
var medium = document.getElementById('medium');
var hard = document.getElementById('hard');
var h2Tags = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var guessNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('guess').value);

easy.addEventListener('click', easyGame);
medium.addEventListener('click', mediumGame);
hard.addEventListener('click', hardGame);

function easyGame() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    difBlocks[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < h2Tags.length; j++) {
    h2Tags[j].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (let k = 0; k < lis.length; k++) {
    lis[k].style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById('guess').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('guesslabel').style.display = 'inline-block';
  document.getElementById('guessrange').innerHTML = 'Between 0 and 10';
  document.getElementById('guessH3').innerHTML = 'Try and guess the number I\'ve been thinking of!';
  lives = 3;
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  createLives(3);
}

function mediumGame() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    difBlocks[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < h2Tags.length; j++) {
    h2Tags[j].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (let k = 0; k < lis.length; k++) {
    lis[k].style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById('guess').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('guesslabel').style.display = 'inline-block';
  document.getElementById('guessrange').innerHTML = 'Between 0 and 100';
  document.getElementById('guessH3').innerHTML = 'Try and guess the number I\'ve been thinking of!';
  lives = 5;
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  createLives(5);
}

function hardGame() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    difBlocks[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < h2Tags.length; j++) {
    h2Tags[j].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (let k = 0; k < lis.length; k++) {
    lis[k].style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById('guess').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('guesslabel').style.display = 'inline-block';
  document.getElementById('guessrange').innerHTML = 'Between 0 and 1000';
  document.getElementById('guessH3').innerHTML = 'Try and guess the number I\'ve been thinking of!';
  lives = 9;
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  createLives(9);
}

function game() {
  if (lives > 0) {
    if (randomNumber === guessNumber) {
      alert('You won!');
    } else if (randomNumber > guessNumber) {
      alert('Go higher!');
      removeLife();
    } else if (randomNumber < guessNumber) {
      alert('Go lower!');
      removeLife();
    } else {
      alert('WTF!!!');
    }
  } else {
    alert(`You lost!\nThe number was ${randomNumber}`);
  }
}

function win() {
  alert('Congrats!\nYou won!')
}

function createLives(value) {
  for (i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    var life = document.createElement("span");
    life.className = 'dot';
    document.getElementById('lives').appendChild(life);
  }
}

function removeLife() {
  document.getElementById('lives').removeChild(document.getElementById('lives').lastChild);
  lives--;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#ruleset {
  font-size: large;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: 500;
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 0.8%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: larger;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.2% auto;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
}

.difficulty {
  line-height: 65%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  min-width: fit-content;
  width: 8.6%;
  margin: 0.8% 0.7% 1% 0.7%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#easy {
  background: rgb(140, 223, 28);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(140, 223, 28, 1) 0%, rgba(68, 214, 51, 1) 50%, rgba(54, 161, 68, 1) 100%);
}

#medium {
  background: rgb(11, 151, 162);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(11, 151, 162, 1) 0%, rgba(24, 152, 205, 1) 50%, rgba(25, 111, 189, 1) 100%);
}

#hard {
  background: rgb(83, 59, 221);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(83, 59, 221, 1) 0%, rgba(95, 19, 149, 1) 50%, rgba(101, 23, 159, 1) 100%);
}

.difficulty:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

#guess,
#guesslabel {
  display: none;
}

.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.2%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
    family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<p id="nothing"> </p>
<h1> Number Guessing Game </h1>
<h2> <span> - </span> Ruleset <span> - </span> </h2>
<ul id="ruleset">
  <li> Pick a number between 0 and 10, 0 and 100 or 0 and 1000. </li>
  <li> You have 3, 5, or 9 guesses based on the chosen difficulty. </li>
  <li> If your guess if wrong, you will get indications. </li>
  <li> You win if you guess the number I've been thinking of. </li>
</ul>
<h2> Are you ready? </h2>
<h2> Pick your desired difficulty: </h2>
<div id="difficulties">
  <div class="difficulty" id="easy">
    <h3> Easy </h3>
    <p> 0 - 10 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="difficulty" id="medium">
    <h3> Medium </h3>
    <p> 0 - 100 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="difficulty" id="hard">
    <h3> Hard </h3>
    <p> 0 - 1000 </p>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 id="guessH3"> </h3>
<h3 id='guessrange'> </h3>
<div id="lives">
</div>
<label for="guess" id="guesslabel"> Enter your guess below: </label>
<input type="text" id="guess">
<input type="submit" onclick="game()">
```

Comment: `var guessNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('guess').value);` this statement will set `guessNumber` when the page loads and never again. Hard to say if that was intentional or not.

Comment: Well, I have tried using the console.log() function at first, and then I tried verifying if there was any error using Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: @HereticMonkey As I said, I just started a couple of days ago, so I might make mistakes, but after all, that's why I joined this community. I'll just try finding a solution to the statement you just pointed out.

Comment: you need to read the guess every time the button is pressed. at the moment guessnumber will always be 0

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the help. After the statement that @HereticMonkey pointed our I successfully modified the code and it works. Thanks, everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First, to help your debugging skills, "WTF" isn't useful information for you. If you put the values you are trying to compare into the message the error becomes clearer because the guessNumber is `NaN`.

```
var guessNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('guess').value);
```

This is set to NaN when the program starts because there is no value set. You need to move this to inside the `game()` function (which is called when the 'Submit' button is clicked) so that it can evaluate the current value.

Comment: Well I used the "wtf" alert function after testing everything else; I did that just to test the conditionals. I successfully modified the script so it works flawlessly now. I appreciate the feedback. Thanks! And hope you have a nice day! ;)

Comment: Happy to help. If this worked for you, please accept it as an answer. Thanks!